# Content type url

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list with 3 different content types. I would like to create a url that leads to creating a new item for each one - does anyone know if this can be done in the M365 environment and if so what the syntax would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using the `ContentTypeId` querystring parameter to NewForm.aspx.

So, if your ContentTypeId is `0x0100524AA836B3D3C645AA562C045097A54A00E360498EDC5F864B9CFEB8D675108B76` for your Fruit list, your link would look like:

`https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/lists/Fruit/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=0x0100524AA836B3D3C645AA562C045097A54A00E360498EDC5F864B9CFEB8D675108B76`

You can then create links for the other content types by swapping out the ids in the URL.

---

Easiest way to get the content type id is to go to List Settings and then click on the content type for the list. The URL will have the full id as the value of the parameter `ctype`.